Новые конфиги wireguard не работают
Развернут сервер на котором запущен докер контейнер с wg-easy с доступом к веб-коносоли. При первом поднятии контейнера я выпустил 10 конфигов все прекрасно работают до сегодняшнего дня, недавно появилась потребность ещё в четырех конфигах, создаются они без проблем, но в интернет не выпускаются, между собой клиент с конфигом и сервер VPN пингуются. Пробовал перезагружать контейнер, перезагружать сервер и службы, результат все тот же, старые конфиги работают - новые нет
